# Error : 'math_real' is not compiled in library ieee

Tags: vhdl, ieee

```
library IEEE;  
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;  
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;  
use IEEE.math_real.all;
```

This is how I declared the libraries in my VHDL code. But the tool gives me an error saying:

> Error : 'math_real' is not compiled in library ieee

I am using JasperGold from Cadence. In that, I am using FPV app.

Has it something to do with the tool? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: i am using JasperGold from cadence. In that i am using FPV app.

Comment: Find the math_real library source and compile it into the ieee library.

Comment: I have checked and library is already compiled into IEEE.

Comment: Then your tool may be looking in the wrong place and finding the wrong compiled library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this question.
I had to analyze it again in Jaspergold with switch option `-lib` and with name IEEE.

```
analyze -vhdl93 -lib ieee \
  ${ROOT_PATH}/resources/IEEE/rtl/vhdl/math_real_p.vhd \
  ${ROOT_PATH}/resources/IEEE/rtl/vhdl/math_real_b.vhd
```

Other packages were compiled into the IEEE library (e.g. `std_logic_1164`) and there was no need to compile them again.

Since `math_real` is not synthesizable, JasperGold had ignored it at the first place.

Comment: I improved the wording a little bit. Don't mix up packages and libraries.